# Spring Security WebMvcConfigurer automated controllers pre-configured http methods explanation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I recently started learning Spring Security and by following the [Official Tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/#scratch) I still have some doubts.

There's a section in the tutorial that shows this code:

```
package com.example.securingweb;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

Then, it shows this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:if="${param.error}">
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And right after that code it says: (format on myself)

> **This Thymeleaf template presents a form that captures a username and
>   password and posts them to /login**. As configured, Spring Security
>   provides a filter that intercepts that request and authenticates the
>   user. If the user fails to authenticate, the page is redirected to
>   /login?error, and your page displays the appropriate error message.
>   Upon successfully signing out, your application is sent to
>   /login?logout, and your page displays the appropriate success message.

So I went to the docs for [WebMvcConfigurer#addViewController](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#addViewControllers-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry-) and it says (format on me):

> ```
> default void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry)
> ```
>
> Configure **simple automated controllers pre-configured with the
>   response status code and/or a view to render the response body**. This
>   is useful in cases where there is no need for custom controller logic
>   -- e.g. render a home page, perform simple site URL redirects, return a 404 status with HTML content, a 204 with no content, and more.

So, trying to understand both formatted (bold) parts on the quoted texts above, do those *automated controllers* contain all HTTP methods?

If possible could you explain a little bit more about how do we access and set data into these controllers?

Comment: No they don't. Those are view controllers and only support GET (as that is what you do when you retrieve a page). If you need something to handle the POST you will need to write a seperate controller for that.

Comment: Then, why does the tutorial mentions that "user and password are posted into /login"?

Comment: Because there is a servlet filter in Spring Security that handles the POST which has nothing to do with a view-controller.

Comment: Could you post your comments as an answer? So that I can accept it